# Unable to sync Android Studio with Maven repository

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to add this libraries to my project:

- [com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.loopj.android%7Candroid-async-http%7C1.4.6%7Cjar)
- [com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev115-1.20.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.apis%7Cgoogle-api-services-analytics%7Cv3-rev115-1.18.0-rc%7Cjar)
- [com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar%7Clibrary%7C1.1.0%7C)

But Android Studio is returning this errors:

> Error:(8, 13) Failed to resolve:
> com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0
>
> Error:(6, 13) Failed to resolve:
> com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6
>
> Error:(7, 13) Failed to resolve:
> com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev115-1.20.0

This is my build.grade file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':librarySmartHotel')
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev115-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Do I have to configure something?? for example com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87 is working perfect and I have not done any configuration.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly try to add to your Project `build.gradle` file following code or just add it to existent repositories

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Also you may have `"Offline mode"` enabled. Check if `File -> Build,Execution,Deployment-> Maven/Gradle "Offline work"` is enabled, if so just disable it and `Sync Gradle`

And let me know results.

Comment: I have just added the code and everything started to work just perfectly, thanks!!

Comment: @CROSP awesome man you made my day, "Offline mode" was the culprit

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle builds which you mentioned perfectly compiled with mine. I suggest you to clean your project and restart android studio and try once again. Please let us know if the problem persists.